# 'wrap around' when slicing in python/numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
```

and I'd like to slice it in such a way, that the entire array is returned, with the first element appended to the end, so `array([10, 20, 30, 40, 10])`, or (as a normal list) `[10, 20, 30, 40, 10]`.

Comment: You could use `np.resize` : `np.resize(a,len(a)+1)`?

Comment: Note that that's the `numpy.resize` function, not the array method. The method has completely different behavior.

Comment: Ah, great, I didn't know about that function; thanks. As far as solutions go, though, it's not really better than my `np.append` suggestion, at least in this case where I only need one additional element.

Comment: Any reason you cannot use `%` and take the modulus?

Comment: In that case I could only get the elements by indexing, is that correct? (I'm thinking `[a[i%len(a)] for i in range(len(a)+1)]` - I'll add it to the question for completeness.) This too is quite verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, as collected from my own findings, from the comments below the original question, and from answers by others:

```py
b1 = a.tolist() + [a[0]]
b2 = np.append(a, a[0])

c1 = [a[i%len(a)] for i in range(len(a)+1)]
c2 = a[np.arange(len(a)+1) % len(a)]

d1 = np.array((*a, a[0]))
d2 = [*a, a[0]]

e = np.resize(a, len(a)+1)

f = np.take(a, range(len(a)+1), mode='wrap')

from itertools import cycle, islice
g = list(islice(cycle(a), len(a)+1))
```

Of these, `c1`, `c2`, `e`, `f` and `g` can be most flexibly/easily adjusted in case more elements (than just the first) must be appended, by changing the `len(a)+1` part of the assignment; `e` is my favourite for readability and brevity.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
>>> np.take(a, np.arange(5), mode='wrap')
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 10])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it's readable and flexible. For my use case I prefer `np.resize` over `np.take`, but I've added it to the list of solutions in the answer.

Comment: @ElRudi Including answers to the question is not the the common practice at SO. It makes the question too long without a reason and duplicates things. You could rather put the methods you've found yourself as another answer(s) to your question. And mark the one that proved most useful to you as the solution (you can accept your own answer as well).

Answer (score 1):

I too needed to 'wrap around' a numpy array. However I, like many who likely view this question, needed to wrap around a multidimensional array.

To do so, simply modify the currently accepted and favored answer.

```
>>> a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
>>> wrap_by = 1
>>> np.resize(a, len(a)+wrap_by)
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 10])

>>> b = np.array([[10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60]])
>>> wrap_by = 1
>>> assert len(b.shape)>1 # 'b' is indeed a multidimensional array
>>> np.resize(b, (len(b)+wrap_by, b.shape[1]))
array([[10, 20],
   [30, 40],
   [50, 60],
   [10, 20]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from the `itertools` library to achieve this

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import itertools
>>> a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
>>> list(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(a), len(a) + 1))
[10, 20, 30, 40, 10]
```

Note that this will produce an iterable, which you do not need to consume at once.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at `cycle` before but couldn't figure out how to make use of it - as it's a generator, slicing isn't working. This is a good solution as well; I'll add it to the list in the question for people stumbling upon it, thanks.